# What's the difference between import"exsisting projects into workspace" and "exsisiting android code into workspace"?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm trying to import zxing android demo code into eclipse,when I'm choose "exsisting projects into workspace" it said can't find the project,however I choose the ""exsisting android code into workspace" it works.I want to know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this happens

- When you are creating an Android Project at your computer and you distribute this project folder to your friend then he/she can use first option "exsisting projects into workspace" or second option "exsisting android code into workspace" , both are valid in this case.
- When some developers upload their codes into svn branches like github, that time some user is not uploading some of projects file ( like .class, .project ), so to import these kinds of project you need second option "exsisting android code into workspace" only.

So normally the project which we download from the internet ( tutorials ) doesnt have those android project's main file because of this you can't use first option to import such examples. You can find such examples in SDK folder too.

In short the project which doesnt have ( .class, .project ) needs to import using second option otherwise first option is used.